# Show Navbar on Scroll: Not Shown on Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a bit of jquery to have a Bootstrap 4 navbar fade in when scrolling down past a certain point, by adding and removing a specific class. However, the code I have won't show the navbar if I reload the page having already scrolled down, and when scrolling back up the CSS transition doesn't fade the bar out but simply pops out of view instantly. How can I fix those issues? Would it be better to rely on purely jquery instead of relying on a CSS class? If so, how would that work? Thanks!

JS:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        if($(window).width() >= 768) 
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 300) {
                $('.navbar-home').addClass("navbar-hide");
            } else {
                $('.navbar-home').removeClass("navbar-hide");
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
  .navbar-home {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  }
.navbar-hide {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to call the same code on page load. Change the listener to:

```
$(window).on("scroll load", function(e) {...})
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on how to fix the fact it doesn't ease-out properly?

Comment: I think that is an issue with using `visibility` property.

Comment: You are right! It needed to be visibility:none not visibility:hidden THANKS!

Comment: Umm, not sure if `visibiilty: none` is a valid property, you might consider not using it at all.

Comment: You are correct, although I'm not certain how it functions without it then, but I removed it and it works.